# jQuery Autocomplete can't replace only part of input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to make autocomplete like on Github.
We have a textarea where we write in it some text. We also put -> '@' and try to auto complete a username.

When we the autocomplete script runs it removes all of the text.

My script:

```
function getSign(text){
  var indexOfAt = text.lastIndexOf('@');
  return indexOfAt;
};

function changeText(event, ui) {
      var selectedElement = event.target.innerText;
      var text = $(this).val();
      text.replace(/@$/ , selectedElement);
      $(this).val(text);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $("textarea#autocomplite").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/feeds/autocomplite_search",
        data: { 
          term: request.term.substr(getSign(request.term)+1,request.term.length-getSign(request.term)).trim() 
        },
        success: function(data){
          for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            data[i] = '@'+data[i];
          }
          return response(data);
        }
      });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 400,
    disabled: true,
    search: function() {
      if ( /\s$/.test($(this).val()) ) {
        $(this).autocomplete('disable');
      };
    },
    select: changeText
  });


  $("textarea#autocomplite").keyup(function() {
    if ( /@$/.test($(this).val()) ) {
      $(this).autocomplete('enable');
    };
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`replace` does not modify the original. Reassign:

```
text = text.replace(/@$/ , selectedElement);
```